# How does one go about detecting printers on the client's machine?

Tags: php, printing

I gave it a look, and the first link it gives is 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.printer-list.php

However it does state that it's for printers connected to the server. What if I wanted to get the models of printers on the client's machine? Is this possible with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this as it would mean a security risk.

Comment: PHP is executing in the server, not the client.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Project has this as a requirement and I already had my doubts as I read the document. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible with PHP, neither with Javascript. The only way I imagine is a Java applet which is embedded into your website.

Comment: All right, thank you. Guess it's back to Java for me. I'll accept this once SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the serverside and therefore has no access to devices attached to the clients computer. You may find something in Javascript (though I don't think it can do that...)

Answer (score 0):

As others has said, not possible. However, why don't you just let your visitors chose printer upon printing instead?

Comment: We're not really printing anything, just getting a list of printers. So I guess this means getting back in bed with Java.